# Kitten's fur clumpy after vet used solution to clean ears?

Tags: cats, grooming

I took my kitten to the vet a few days ago and they used a solution to clean her ears out. The solution dripped below and around her ears and has clumped her fur - it feels like there is gel or something in it.

I have tried to wash it out with water and used cat shampoo twice, but nothing seems to work. Also she is long haired.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may need to cut it out. Have you got a photo?

Comment: this might sound strange but you might use a drop of baby oil on the sticky stuff and rub it in gently before you use the shampoo and water to whash it off again.

Comment: @trondhansen that doesn't sound strange, I've had to do similar things to remove elastoplast from my horse's coat. Maybe write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

ALOT of vet cleaning solutions are made with alcohol as a drying and disinfecting agent, as well as tea tree oil, mineral oil, etc for soothing it or relieving itch. A mix of these to ingredients is probably the cause. The oils used can make the hair greasy/oily thus binding the coat hairs together.

I would try simple clear dish soap with no additives or scents, like clear dawn, with warm to cool water (the hotter the water the more damaging to the skin as well as it's fur). It's a degreaser which will remove the oils in the fur which may be the cause, but more importantly it's very safe for cats and kittens. It's even used for oil spill animal victims, and used to treat fleas in kittens and puppies that are too young for pyrethrin exposure. I would try this, and make sure it's rinsed out completely until there are no suds or bubbles. It being a degreaser should help with the clumping, and should make it much easier to gently comb out any remaining tangles.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sticky stuff out of the fur I suggest using baby oil to first soften
and dissolve it.

Using baby oil is a mild way to do this and can be used on most animals.

This might be used to remove several types of sticky stuff in a pets fur like oil and gum.

When the stuff is softened and this might take a little
time.

Wash it off with a mild soap or shampoo and water.

Be sure to get the soap cleaned off as good as you can.